# modify WordPress tagging system with custom tagging system

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to replace the default tagging system on WordPress with my own tagging system/category tagger by developing a Plugin. I'm new to WordPress, I was wondering what resources I look into to achieve this?

Comment: why negative comment?

Answer (score 0):

You would look into the Codex:

- [Writing_a_Plugin](http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin)
- [Taxonomies#Custom_Taxonomies](http://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies#Custom_Taxonomies)

And at WordPress Answers: [`register_taxonomy`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=register_taxonomy%20is:a) and [`<plugin-development>`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plugin-development?sort=votes&pageSize=50).